# Lectura frecuencias Arduino

Tags: arduino

Estoy haciendo un afinador de guitarra con arduino. Me compré el micrófono MAX4466 de Adafruit. He escrito un código, pero me da valores con mucho ruido y con muy poca precision. No sé como podría mejorar el código de lectura:

```
float startTime=0;
float stopTime=0;
float sampleTime=0;
int peaks=0;
float period=0;
float frequency=0;
int sample [660];

void(loop){
peaks=0;
    startTime=millis();                            //start of sampling
    for(int i=0; i<660; i++){                      //takes 800 samples of the input
      sample[i]=analogRead(A0);                   //read the guitar input (sinusoid)
      delay(1);
    }
    stopTime = millis();                          //stop time in miliseconds 
    sampleTime = ((stopTime-startTime));          //the time it takes for all 800 samples is equal to stop time-start time
    for(int k=0; k<660; k++){                      
      if ((sample[k]>sample[k-1])  &  (sample[k]>sample[k+1])) //determines the number of peaks after 800 samples 
      {
        peaks++;
      }
    }
    period = sampleTime/peaks;                                 
    frequency = 1000.0/period;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que el ruido venga por ese `delay(1)` que tienes en el bucle de muestreo.

Si analizamos la frecuencia de cada cuerda y obtenemos la duración de una pulsación:

```
1ra cuerda: 629,63 Hz -> 1/629,63 = 0,001588 =  1,588 ms
2da cuerda: 246,94 Hz -> 1/246,94 = 0,004049 =  4,049 ms
3ra cuerda: 196,00 Hz -> 1/196,00 = 0,005102 =  5,102 ms
4ta cuerda: 146,83 Hz -> 1/146,83 = 0,006810 =  6,810 ms
5ta cuerda: 110,00 Hz -> 1/110,00 = 0,009090 =  9,090 ms
6ta cuerda:  82,40 Hz -> 1/ 82,40 = 0,012135 = 12,135 ms
```

En frecuencias bajas como la de la primera cuerda, el pulso dura hasta 12 ms, por lo que un delay de 1 ms `delay(1)` no tiene un gran impacto. Sin embargo, en frecuencias altas como la primera cuerda, 1 ms supone 2/3 del ciclo, por lo que el muestreo en muchos casos se saltará el pico.

Siendo estrictos, según el Teorema de [Nyquist-Shannon](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_muestreo_de_Nyquist-Shannon) la [frecuencia de muestreo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frecuencia_de_muestreo#Teorema_de_Nyquist) debe ser almenos el doble que la frecuencia máxima de la señal a muestrear.

Para el caso de mayor frecuencia de la primera cuerda, debería realizarse un muestreo teórico de:

```
630 Hz * 2 = 1260 Hz
```

Esto es, 1260 muestras por segundo. Si entre cada muestra hay un delay de 1 ms, y suponiendo un caso ideal en el que el resto del operaciones del bucle se realiza en 0 segundos, tendríamos un máximo de 1000 muestras por segundo, que es inferior a las 1260 muestras.

Si no hay muestras suficientes, al recrear la señal se produce lo que se conoce como aliasing. En la imagen, la señal continua inicial (roja) se muestrea a baja a menos frecuencia de la necesaria y la señal recreada (azul) tiene una frecuencia menor.

[image: Aliasing]

De esta manera, si las muestras saltan máximos de la señal original, se obtienen lecturas incorrectas. Por lo que convendría eliminar o, al menos, reducir el delay (desconozco si está ahí por alguna razón en especial).

Por otro lado, quizá te interese probar con la función `pulseIn()` de arduino. Aunque no se cómo se comportará al tratarse de una sinusoide y no de un pulso digital y no lo he probado dado que no tengo micro para arduino.

En caso de que tengas un arduino Zero, MKRZero o MKR1000 puedes usar la librería [`AudioFrequencyMeter.h`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AudioFrequencyMeter).

**Edito:**

Aquí un gráfico que recrea la señal con los datos concretos de este caso en MATLAB:

```
>> f = 630;                 % Frecuencia de la señal de audio
>> x1 = [0:0.00001:1];      % Eje temporal para la señal original
>> x2 = [0:1/1000:1];       % Eje temporal para la señal con 1000 muestras
>> y1 = sin(2*pi*f*x1);     % Señal original de 630 Hz
>> y2 = sin(2*pi*f*x2);     % Señal de 630 hz (f) muestreada a 1000 muestras por segundo
>> plot(x1,y1,x2,y2);
```

[image: Muestreo]

En ocasiones hay una distancia de pico a pico de hasta 2 ciclos, resultando en una lectura de la mitad de la frecuencia real.